# Fixing a youtube downloader class

Tags: c#, .net, download, youtube, webclient

A Little time ago I opend a thread (link at the bottom).
And I'm happy to say it has been fixed, that is partially.
It still uses the wrong youtube links.
And since youtube keeps updating all examples i could find where broken.
I think this has to do with the "regular" expressions.
Could someone enlighten me on that subject?

And now for the error at hand:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
At Line 22: wc.DownloadFile(kvp.Value, @"C:\Users\waralot\Downloads\youtube\"+kvp.Key);

The console during compilation is here: pastebin.com/BrgKkAmk

Original project at HackForums: http://www.hackforums.net/showthread.php?tid=2052105

My current version: http://pastebin.com/2iH2vQ2L

Again my first thread can be found here: [Converting a Youtube downloader form VB to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957429)

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: Looks like Youtube is denying direct access to the video files.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Youtube blocks you from accessing the link, this may because you don't set an `user-agent` for your `WebClient`.

Try adding this before you try to download the video.

```
wc.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
```

Code for url cleanup also needs to be changed like so.

```
//clean up residual tags and encoded strings
link = slink.Replace("url=", "");
link = link.Replace("\\u0026", "&");
link = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(link);
```

Comment: I tryed that. And added a try catch thingy.
But it complained about the lenght of the url...
Can you have a go and compile it?

Comment: you didn't work with the result of the `string.Replace` method, so your url was always wrong. i edited the fix, worked for me like this. And for the next time, try to post the exception, otherwise people might not help you.